# number of comparisons in recursive algorithm taken into account

Tags: algorithm, sorting, comparison, time-complexity

In (most of the) research papers on sorting, authors conclude that their algorithm takes `n-1`comparisons to sort a 'n' sized array (where n is size of the array)
...so and so
but when it comes to coding, the code uses more comparisons than concluded.
More specifically, what assumptions do they take for the comparisons?

What kind of comparisons they don't take into account?

Like if you take a look at freezing sort or Enhanced Insertion sort. The no. Of comparisons, these algo  take in actual code is more than they have specied in the graph(no. of comparisons vs no. of elements)

Comment: Huh?! Can you give an example?

Comment: Not enough information to reproduce the problem. Link to, or quote, an article, and show code that purports to implement an algorithm described therein

Comment: The only place I can think of, where n-1 might come into play would be the worst case recursion depth. If you find an algorithms that needs only n-1 comparisons in total to sort an array, you could earn a lot of money...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is for specific questions about coding with definite answers. Discussions of high-level design concepts and best practices are more appropriate for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). Please read [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82990/228805) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The *least possible* number of comparisons done in a sorting algorithm could be `n-1`. In this case, you wouldn't actually be sorted at all, you'd just be checking whether the data is already sorted, essentially just comparing each element to the ones directly before and after it (this is done in the best case for [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)). It's fairly easy to see that it's impossible to do less comparisons than this, because then you'd have more than one disjoint sets of what you've compared, meaning you wouldn't know how the elements across these sets compare to each other.

If we're talking about average / worst case, [it's actually been proven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list) that the number of comparisons required is Ω(n log n).

An algorithm being recursive or iterative doesn't (directly) affect the number of comparisons. The only statement I could think that we could make specifically about recursive sorting algorithms is perhaps the recursion depth. This greatly depends on the algorithm, but [quick-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), specifically, has a (worst-case) recursion depth around `n-1`.

Answer (score 0):

1. More comparisons that are often ignored on papers, but are conducted
   in real code are the comparisons for branches. (`if (<stop clause>)
   return ...;`), and similarly for loop iterators.

   - One reason why they are mostly ignored is because they are done on
     indices, which are of constant sizes, while the compared elements
     (which we do count) - might take more time, depending on the actual
     type being compared (strings might take longer to compare than
     integers, for example).
2. Also note, an array cannot be sorted using `n-1` comparisons
   (worst/average case), since sorting is `Omega(nlogn)` problem.
   However, it is possible what the authour meant is the sorting takes
   `n-1` comparisons at each step of the algorithm, and there could be
   multiple (typically `O(logn)`) of those steps.